# trying to WHOIS a site within IRC

Tags: python, sockets, irc, whois

```
      if data.find('!whois') != -1:
         s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      s.connect(("com.whois-servers.net", 43))
         s.send('www.msn.com' + "\r\n")
         response = ''
         while True:
              d = s.recv(4096)
              response += d
              if d == '':
                  break
         s.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + response + '\r\n')
         s.close()
```

when I type !whois on the channel, it doesnt do anything, I'm probably doing this wrong. Any help will be appreciate it. Thanks.

Note: There's another socket already connected.

Comment: What version of python are you using? And please don't mix single and double quotes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works in python3.1 with the whois site you mentioned.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

domain = "msn"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("com.whois-servers.net", 43))
s.send(("%s\r\n" % domain).encode())
response = ""

while True:
  r = s.recv(4096).decode()
  response += r
  if r == "":
      break
print(response)
```